# reopen "closed questions" if they get referred as origin for a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions

There was this question:

[The difference between stellen, abstellen, aufstellen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49969/the-difference-between-stellen-abstellen-aufstellen/49987)

It got closed March 6 of 2019.

Because of considering it a dupe to this question:
[What's the difference between stellen and aufstellen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48296/whats-the-difference-between-stellen-and-aufstellen)

Which got closed on December 18 of 2018. Because of "too broad".

What I see: the "closed origin" has an upvoted answer, so it was a good answer for some people. The missing "answer tick" by the questioner - not so important.

**-> should the "origin" then not be reopened?**

(I thought I saw this more often, my [search for duplicate:yes](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1yes) is quite long.)

Side note:

I additionally found chain linking of dupes:

- [Can someone point me to an easy resource that teaches the German language?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/can-someone-point-me-to-an-easy-resource-that-teaches-the-german-language)

  - dupe chain links happen on SE.meta too: [What is best way to find duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160719/what-is-best-way-to-find-duplicate-questions)